# Smooth gradient display of function of two (xy) variables in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot, gradient

I'd like to show the values of a function of 2 variables, say `x+y`, as a "bitmap" image. So I tried this, based on http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/heatmaps.html:

```
# Color runs from white to green
set palette rgbformula -7,2,-7
set cbrange [-5:5]
set cblabel "Value"
unset cbtics
set xrange [-4.5:4.5]
set yrange [-4.5:4.5]
set view map
splot x+y with image
```

... but I get nothing:

```
$ gnuplot -persist test.gp
"test.gp", line 45: warning: Image grid must be at least 2 x 2.
```

[image: test.png]

So how can I get the "pixel" at, say, x=-2, y=-2 to be colored according to `x+y`=-4 on the `cbrange`?

---

Edit: got that:

```
set palette rgbformula -7,2,-7
set cbrange [-5:5]
set cblabel "Value"
unset cbtics
set xrange [-4.5:4.5]
set yrange [-4.5:4.5]
set pm3d
unset surface
set view map
splot x+y
```

Outputs:

[image: test.png]

---

But - say I want the gradient in this range, exported as "smooth" gradient (no axes, ticks, marks of any kind) on a big PNG, say 3000x2000 pixels; what would be the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from your edit: You just to deactivate every thing. Meaning:

```
unset colorbox
unset xtics
unset ytics
set border 0
```

Then id you create the command list:

```
set palette rgbformula -7,2,-7
set cbrange [-5:5]
unset cblabel 
unset cbtics
set xrange [-4.5:4.5]
set yrange [-4.5:4.5]
set pm3d
unset surface
set view map

unset colorbox
unset xtics
unset ytics
set border 0

splot x+y
```

You get only the gradient
[image]

**EDIT:** In order to improve the gradient step and create a smoother image you need to use `pm3d`'s `interpolate`.

```
set pm3d interpolate 4,4
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that, @ctheo - but here I am interested in obtaining a "smooth" gradient; here also in your image, the gradient is shown as "boxes" - I'd ideally like every pixel in the exported image to be its own shade of green (as per the formula). Is that possible?

Comment: @sdaau now I get your request. Edited the answer. You can try the parameters of `interpolate` to find out your preferable gradient.

Comment: To remove all margins use also `set lmargin at screen 0; set rmargin at screen 1; set tmargin at screen 1; set bmargin at screen 0`

Comment: Many thanks for that @ctheo - that looks great; accepted! `:)` Btw, any thoughts on `set samples` and `set isosamples`? They seem to have an effect too, but I couldn't really control them... Cheers!